# Reducing the width of div from both left and right at the same time

Tags: html, css

how to reduce the width of div from both left and right at the same time when i mouse over the div?

something like this ->  [example](https://youtu.be/Ne8asC_uD4Q)

i don't know why the bottom div is just reduced from left.

```css
    #border-top-category {
        position: absolute;
        border-top: solid 20px rgb(234, 198, 255);
        width: 100px;
        top: 0px;
        right: 10px;
        transition: width 2s;
        }
#border-top-category:hover {
       width: 50px;
       }
```

```html
          <div id="border-top-category"></div>
```

Comment: maybe consider scale instead of width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of animating the width, you could change the scale of the element on hover.
Set the default `scaleX` to 1 and change it on hover to 0.

Your CSS code could then look like this:

```css
    #border-top-category {
        position: absolute;
        border-top: solid 20px rgb(234, 198, 255);
        width: 100px;
        transform: scaleX(1);
        transform-origin: center;
        top: 0px;
        right: 10px;
        transition: transform 2s;
    }

    #border-top-category:hover {
        transform: scaleX(0);
    }
```

```html
<div id="border-top-category"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#border-top-category {
    position: absolute;
    border-top: solid 20px rgb(234, 198, 255);
    width: 100px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 10px;
    transition: transform 2s;
    }
    #border-top-category:hover {
   transform: scaleX(0.5);
   }
```

Use transition to transform the X axis (scaleX(k) it will make the x axis to k time)

Comment: This might help.